# SQL Server : how to create tables in stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server

Task: write a SQL script to build a table. Call the script `spCreateTable()`, it should accept one argument, a `varchar` called `subjectOfTable`.

`subjectOfTable` is a `varchar` containing the subject of the table. Some examples are example “Employee” or “Formula.” Your script will use that subject to build the table name, primary key, and natural key.

For example, given “Employee” as the subject, your script will build a table called `tEmployee` with a surrogate key called `EmployeeID` and a natural key called `Employee`. Be sure to create the necessary constraints for the keys.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateTable]
    @subjectOfTable VARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID  (@tabName) AND type in (N'U'))
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[@tabName]

    CREATE TABLE @tabName
    (
        [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [RankID] [INT] NOT NULL,
        [SlotTime] [NVARCHAR](10) NOT NULL,
        [SlotDate] [NVARCHAR](30) NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
END
```

This is what I have so far, any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! But...is this a homework assignment? We're not supposed to help with those.

Comment: No. I can see why you would think that though. I'm trying to send someone a table by using a store procedure, so they can just execute it. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to figure it out.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with helping someone on a homework assignment, but they should have tried something, failed, and ask questions with clear problem statements. Ideally, if that did occur before the assignment due date, they could ask their instructor, but usually these are last minute.

Comment: Please **DO NOT** store dates as `NVARCHAR`! There are date-specific datatypes for a good reason - use `DATE` if you only need date (no time), or `DATETIME2(n)` if you need both date and time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the table with a generic name, and then use the sp_rename stored procedure to rename it to the variable name:

```
CREATE TABLE IF EXISTS sp_CreateTable_TempTable (
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RankID] [int] NOT NULL,
[SlotTime] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[SlotDate] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

EXEC sp_rename sp_CreateTable_TempTable, @subjectOfTable;
GO
```

Comment: You can also use dynamic sql to create a CREATE TABLE script, but this is cleaner.

Comment: MUCH cleaner then dynamic SQL! But, if the column names/types were to become parameters too, then dynamic SQL would be required.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF EXISTS sp_CreateTable_TempTable`. `SQL Server` does not support such construct. Also why would anyone wants to create the table if it already exists ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment, I'll just throw it out here
What's the real usage of this code anyway? to create table often but same with columns?

I don't know how other person will run this (in SSMS? in application?)

FYI SSMS also has Template for create table (Ctrl+Alt+T), then he/she can press Ctrl+Shift+M to fill in the parameters every time.

If the columns are fixed, you can customize first and send it to them so they only change the  part

```
-- =========================================
-- Create table template
-- =========================================
USE <database, sysname, AdventureWorks>
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('<schema_name, sysname, dbo>.<table_name, sysname, sample_table>', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE <schema_name, sysname, dbo>.<table_name, sysname, sample_table>
GO

CREATE TABLE <schema_name, sysname, dbo>.<table_name, sysname, sample_table>
(
    <columns_in_primary_key, , c1> <column1_datatype, , int> <column1_nullability,, NOT NULL>, 
    <column2_name, sysname, c2> <column2_datatype, , char(10)> <column2_nullability,, NULL>, 
    <column3_name, sysname, c3> <column3_datatype, , datetime> <column3_nullability,, NULL>, 
    CONSTRAINT <contraint_name, sysname, PK_sample_table> PRIMARY KEY (<columns_in_primary_key, , c1>)
)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

[first: prefixing a stored procedure should be usually avoided](http://www.sqlnuggets.com/blog/do-not-prefix-stored-procedures-with-sp_/)

you can use dynamic sql like that: ([but better read that before](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html))

```
BEGIN TRAN;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateTable]
    ( @Tabname    SYSNAME 
    , @SchemaName NVARCHAR(128) = NULL
    ) AS
BEGIN;
    SET @SchemaName = ISNULL (@SchemaName, N'dbo');  
    IF ( SELECT object_id (@SchemaName + N'.'+@tabname ) ) IS NOT NULL
       EXEC ( N'DROP TABLE ' + @SchemaName + N'.'+@tabname)
    EXEC (N'CREATE TABLE ' + @SchemaName + N'.'+@tabname + N'
    (   [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [RankID] [INT] NOT NULL,
        [SlotTime] TIME NOT NULL,
        [SlotDate] DATE NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]' 
    );
    RETURN 0;
 END;
 GO
SELECT OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.test')  AS OBJECT_ID
EXEC [dbo].[CreateTable] @tabname = test
SELECT OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.test')  AS OBJECT_ID

ROLLBACK
```